# Xp_cmdshell - loosing printing properties durning printing file pdf

Tags: sql-server, foxit-reader

I'm printing PDF files from MSSQL Server 2014.
I'm using FoxitReader to silent print.

I set settings in regedit to print correctly from normal cmd.exe ( fit to page) and it works from cmd:

```
"E:\FoxitReader\FoxitReader.exe" /t "\\xxxx\xxxx\Test\xxx.pdf" "Kyocera FS-3920DN XPS"
```

but when I'm trying to print via XP_CMDSHELL from SQL query:

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'E: & "E:\FoxitReader\FoxitReader.exe" /t "\\xxxx\xxxx\Test\xxx.pdf" "Kyocera FS-3920DN XPS"'
```

I'm losing all printer settings and options. My pdf is little bit cutted.
MSSQL ignores every printer and software settings.

Comment: The account you used to set registry settings is probably not the sql server service account - so the changes you made are not visible to that acccount. Sign on to the server machine with the service account and make your registry changes. Then try testing after that change from the command line first to verify that it works.

Comment: Thanks, for your reply. I solve the problem with installing another pdf reader and it works '"C:\Program Files\bioPDF\PDF Writer\pdfcmd.exe" command=printpdf input="\\xx\xx\xxx\x.pdf" printer="Kyocera FS-3920DN KX"' I lost few hours to get good print, maybe someone read this and it will help.